# How to use boolean in 2 functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, button, boolean

```
var anchor = document.querySelectorAll('button');
var menuOpen = false;

[].forEach.call(anchor, function(anchor) {


    anchor.onclick = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (menuOpen == false) {
            this.classList.add('close');
            menuOpen = true;

        } else {

            this.classList.remove('close');
            menuOpen = false;

        }
    }
});

$('body').on("click", function(e) {


    if (menuOpen == true) {

        document.getElementById("cross").classList.remove('close');
        menuOpen = false;
    }
});
```

Current Situation: When I close my menu on click on any links in my menu. My menu closes but my button still shows the 'close' class. I want to remove the 'close' class on any click on the page. But also checking the boolean if the menu has been closed.

Somehow my body on click function is not doing it correctly.. to check and to remove the cross button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need of `flag`. You can check if any `button` is having class `close` as follow. Also, converted whole code to use `jQuery`.

See the comments inline in the code.

```
// On all button click
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation(); // Prevent event bubbling

    $(this).toggleClass('close'); // Toggle class 'close' of the clicked button
});


// On body click
$('body').on('click', function() {
    if ($('button.close').length) { // Check if any button is having class 'close'
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        $('#cross').removeClass('close'); // Remove 'close' class of '#cross'
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Tushar, somehow it doesn't work when i use chrome to preview in iphone6 emulator. Should this be happening? Actually not just iPhone 6.

Comment: @JamesTan Don't trust emulators, they just gives you the same resolution as device

Comment: Hi Tushar, I just tested on the real device and it is really not working. Any workaround with this? That the devices can use also?

Comment: Hi Tushar, it is really not working on any device right now. Only works on browser :( Do you have any workaround with this?

Comment: @JamesTan Do you see any error in console. Use `remote debugging` to debug your problem. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/remote-debugging-ios-safari-on-os-x-windows-and-linux/